# Compare textbox values in multiple edits

Tags: jquery

What I have here comparing value of textboxes. I used this for multiple editing records in mysql. But the problem is my script isn't working. Why is that?

Any help will appreciate.

**HTML**

```
<input id="n_quantity" value="">
<input id="pr_total" value="">
<input type="submit" id="sbtBtn">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#sbtBtn').on('click', function () {
    var textBox1 = parseInt($("#n_quantity").val());
    var textBox2 = parseInt($("#pr_total").val());
    for (var i = 0; i < textBox1; i++) {
        if ((textBox2[i].value) > textBox1[i].value) {
            alert('value is greater than quantity');
            return false;
        } else {}
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you define "isn't working" for us?

Comment: @DavidThomas the [i] isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you used `looping` you have a `single textbox` and you are taking value of `textbox` in `textbox1` so `textbox1[i]` is `undefined` and you are comparing values of `undefined elements` try this,

```
if ((textBox2) > textBox1) {
   alert('value is greater than quantity');
   return false;
} else {}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/mYjtx/2/)

**Updated** if you have multiple `quantities` and `total` then use `class` instead of `id`, as `id` must be `unique` like,

**HTML**

```
<input class="n_quantity" value="">
<input class="pr_total" value="">
<br/>
<input class="n_quantity" value="">
<input class="pr_total" value="">
<br/>
<input type="submit" id="sbtBtn">
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#sbtBtn').on('click', function () {
    var textBox1 = $(".n_quantity");
    var textBox2 = $(".pr_total");
    for (var i = 0,len=textBox1.length; i < len;i++) {
        if (parseInt(textBox2[i].value) > parseInt(textBox1[i].value)) {
            alert('value is greater than quantity');
            break;
        } else {}
    }
});
```

[Updated class Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/mYjtx/1/)

Comment: that's it! But I should try it first in code with mysql records.

Comment: You said, your `script` is not working. Now I solved your `script` problem, I think. If you have `mysql` problem then edit your question or accept this answer and come up with a new question.

Answer (score 0):

why u want go for looping..

```
 $('#sbtBtn').click(function () {
        var textBox1 = parseInt($("#n_quantity"));
        var textBox2 = parseInt($("#pr_total"));

        for (var i = 0,len=textBox1.length; i < len;i++) {
            if ((textBox2[i].val()) > textBox1[i].val()) {
                alert('value is greater than quantity');
                return false;
            }
         }
    });
    });
```

just go thorugh fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/avmCX/17/